# package filemanager github

Tags: laravel, unisharp-file-manager

Good morning, I downloaded the filemanager package via github and went through all the steps, but it gives me this error when I run it. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if downloading the source is the correct way to install. You might have more luck following the [Installation](https://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation) instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the path of the file. Do also check uploaded file in storage folder.

Also you need to run create a symlink between storage and public directory to access the file:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: I did everything and created the folders, but I do not know why it's wrong.
I am a beginner Laravel programmer and I am not very fluent in English. I apologize if I made a mistake. I use Google for translation